# Add NSMutableAttributedString that results to HTML h1 element if converted

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I am using the following code to create a `NSAttributedString`.

```
let titleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24),
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
    .paragraphStyle: {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.headIndent = 1.0
        return paragraphStyle
    }()
]

let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "H1 title", attributes: titleAttributes)
```

And using this code to convert it to HTML.

```
let htmlData = try! attributedText.data(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length), documentAttributes: [
    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
])

let htmlString = String(data: htmlData, encoding: .utf8)!
```

The element that contains the `H1 title`, is a `p` and `span` tags.

```html
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">My Title</span></p>
```

I guess, it is as such by default.

Is there a way to specify that `attributedString` is a HTML `H1` element?